# Using IK to make a cutscene in Unity 2021

Tags: unity, animation

I imported a character from Mixamo to Unity, and I wanted to make a quick fight cutscene.

[image]

However, I realized that it was going to take a good bit of time. I would like to know if there is a method of animating that uses Inverse Kinematics to make animations in Unity. That way, things would go much quicker. Thank You!

Comment: Unity is not really intended as a 3D animation authoring tool. You can stretch it to achieve that if absolutely necessary, but you'll have a better experience with richer tool support in basically any other DCC software that will export the animation as an asset to import into Unity.

Comment: You don't "quickly" animate a fight cutscene. Those always take a lot of work to get right. Whenever you have animations where two characters touch each other, things get complicated. Even AAA games often do a lot of camera trickery to avoid putting too much work into animating fights in cutscenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual workflow for creating animations for Unity games is to create them in a 3rd party 3d modeling program like Blender, Maya or 3dsMax and then import the animations into Unity as animation actions by importing the model. Unity can retarget animations via the [Avatar component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfiguringtheAvatar.html), so you don't necessarily need to do the animations with the same model which you are going to apply them to.

But if you still want to do it in Unity, then the new [3d rigging system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.animation.rigging@1.3/manual/index.html) might be what you want. It's basically a more advanced and flexible alternative to the [build-in IK system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html) provided by Unity. Although the basic IK system might do the job if you only want IK for hands, feet and gaze. The article I linked has an example script.

In either case you would create your IK targets as invisible game objects and then create actions using the [Animation System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationOverview.html) which move those IK targets around.